# Proguard doesn't change mapping

Tags: android, proguard

I have changed/added some methods in one of my classes. Shouldn't this make Proguard change the mapping? I would like this class to be obfuscated with different mapping from the previous release, but it doesn't. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProGuard's mapping will indeed be different, but the differences depend on the changes in the original code. Many new methods might just get an obfuscated name 'a', without affecting the renaming of the other methods.

If you really want to have a different mapping, you can specify a randomized obfuscation dictionary (-obfuscationdictionary).